# building smooth animation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, animation

First here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace winform_project
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    void movement_correct(PictureBox pic, int i)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
        pic.Top += (i - 1);
        pic.Left += (i + 3);
    }

    void movement_up(PictureBox pic, int i)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
        pic.Top -= (i - 1);
        pic.Left -= (i + 3);
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            movement_correct(pictureBox1, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox2, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox3, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox4, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox5, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox6, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox7, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox8, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox9, i);
            movement_correct(pictureBox10, i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            movement_up(pictureBox1, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox2, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox3, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox4, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox5, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox6, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox7, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox8, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox9, i);
            movement_up(pictureBox10, i);
        }

    }
 }
}
```

There are 10 dummy picture boxes. Whenever i click the button they start to move a bit(sort of like the enemies in space invaders).

I am trying to make a smooth animation in winforms. The problem is that the animation in not as smooth as i want it to be. In my code all the boxes aren't moving simultaneously, there is a little bit of noticeable gap in their movement. What i want is smooth movement.

I was thinking of multi threading it but then realized it would mean one thead for each objects. Is there any other way(Within winforms).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tag this WinForms.  Doubt multi threading is not going to help.   Can you go WPF?

Comment: sleeping for 25ms each control movement will result in it moving the controls at 4 fps. This will be noticeably slow.

Comment: @JamesB 25ms between each frame makes 40 fps. Looks like a little typo. However, the human eye [perceives roughly 10-12 fps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate), so anything above that is considered ok.

Comment: @WinCoder Winforms isn't made for games (with animations). Use a different technology, there are several alternatives out there (You may want to look into XNA, since you're using C#).

Comment: @Msonic but with 10 controls, making each full loop 250ms

Comment: @JamesB Oh, I hadn't seen it being called multiple times, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Thread.Sleep(n)` for timing purposes is a guaranteed way of not getting smooth animation; this is because the value passed to `Thread.Sleep` is treated by the OS as a minimum sleep time, meaning that the actual duration of the sleep can be (and usually is) a bit longer. You should instead drive your animation using [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2635/High-Performance-Timer-in-C).

Even with a proper high-resolution timing engine, you will still have "tearing" effects.

Comment: the comments on the link suggested using stopwatch class. Even then,as you said, there was no noticeable difference in the "smoothness" of the animation. I guess its one of those limitations of a technology.

Comment: No, it's possible to do perfectly smooth animation in Winforms (except for "tearing" which is a different problem). Post your modified code (using QueryPerformanceCounter) and it should be possible for us to determine the problem. You should not still have any `Thread.Sleep(n)` calls in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this.SuspendLayout()` and `this.ResumeLayout()` in your for loops will help keep all boxes moving at the same time. It may not get you the smoothness, but it will keep everything moving as one.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the `sleep()` out of the methods and doing it once in loop iteration will reduce the delay from (more than 250ms) to (a little more than 25ms) between each box's `movement_correct()` and `movement_up()` call.